# Laravel group by & sum query

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

If I have following data in my Laravel table:

| id | event | venue | attendees |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Event one | gallery | 5 |
| 2 | Event two | big hall | 11 |
| 3 | Event three | gallery | 6 |
| 4 | Event four | big hall | 24 |
| 5 | Event five | gallery | 7 |

Is it possible to write Eloquent query to get number of events at each venue and sum of attendees per each venue, like in following table?

| venue | events | attendees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| big hall | 2 | 35 |
| gallery | 3 | 18 |

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In L8

You can use the `withSum()` aggregate function :

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

```
Venue::withCount('events')->withSum('events', 'attendees')->get();
```

Before L8:

```
Venue::withCount([
    'events',
    'events as events_sum_attendees' => function($query){
        return $query->select(                      
            DB::raw('SUM(attendees)');
    }
    ])->get();
```

Comment: I guess your example would work if I had 2 tables/models - 'venues' and 'events'?  

Since I have data in only one table, I assume simple SELECT query would be enough?  

`$result = DB::select('SELECT venue, COUNT(event), SUM(attendees) FROM table GROUP BY venue');`